# how to sych sqlite data with server in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, synchronization, icloud

I am making one app, saved data in sqlite. Now as per latest requirement I want to fetch same data on other device where I logged in. So what way I should follow to keep data common to all device. App is offline, we can use internet only for synching purpose.

```
I have done some part as :
 1. Make same database on PHP server.
 2. Save local data with flag isSynch=No.
 3. After saving it, when I connect to internet I make txt file of each table by fetching rows with isSynch=NO and on server side all these data gets dumped to database.
 4. After successful insertion of data on server, it makes txt files of all tables with flag isSynch=YES.
 5. Now all files get downloaded to local device and inserted to each table.
```

Can I use iCloud for it ? Or tell me any other solution if there.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data and iCloud should do it for you. You can sync the Core Data database between devices.  I would suggest you read up on Core Data, or maybe take look here to see a video of a Core Data app using iCloud to sync.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/